# Consumir Web Api php

Tags: php, xml, asp.net-web-api

Eu preciso consumir o seguinte XML:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <NewDataSet>
        <CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
            <Codigo_Municipio>2700201</Codigo_Municipio>
            <codigo_pais>1058</codigo_pais>
            <Pais>BRASIL</Pais>
            <sigla_uf>AL</sigla_uf>
            <Uf>ALAGOAS (AL)</Uf>
            <Municipio>ANADIA</Municipio>
            <Codigo_franqueado>490</Codigo_franqueado>
            <Franqueado>ANDERSON TESTE</Franqueado>
        </CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
        <CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
            <Codigo_Municipio>3100203</Codigo_Municipio>
            <codigo_pais>1058</codigo_pais>
            <Pais>BRASIL</Pais>
            <sigla_uf>MG</sigla_uf>
            <Uf>MINAS GERAIS (MG)</Uf>
            <Municipio>ABAETE</Municipio>
            <Codigo_franqueado>490</Codigo_franqueado>
            <Franqueado>ANDERSON TESTE</Franqueado>
        </CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
    </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

Eu preciso procurar, por exemplo, 3100203 e o nome do Municipio ABAETE

Este XML está em uma URL, com o método GET vou consumir esses dados em um site em PHP.

Comment: Nesse caso parece que você precisa deserializar o XML, não recebê-lo de um web-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você está tentando interpretar o XML que recebeu do web-api. Nesse caso, pode usar o `SimpleXML` do próprio PHP para interpretar. Seja em baixo um exemplo simples usando o `SimpleXMLElement`, usando o seu XML mesmo, e extraindo os dados que você deu como exemplo:

```
<?php
$xml = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">
    <NewDataSet>
        <CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
            <Codigo_Municipio>2700201</Codigo_Municipio>
            <codigo_pais>1058</codigo_pais>
            <Pais>BRASIL</Pais>
            <sigla_uf>AL</sigla_uf>
            <Uf>ALAGOAS (AL)</Uf>
            <Municipio>ANADIA</Municipio>
            <Codigo_franqueado>490</Codigo_franqueado>
            <Franqueado>ANDERSON TESTE</Franqueado>
        </CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
        <CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
            <Codigo_Municipio>3100203</Codigo_Municipio>
            <codigo_pais>1058</codigo_pais>
            <Pais>BRASIL</Pais>
            <sigla_uf>MG</sigla_uf>
            <Uf>MINAS GERAIS (MG)</Uf>
            <Municipio>ABAETE</Municipio>
            <Codigo_franqueado>490</Codigo_franqueado>
            <Franqueado>ANDERSON TESTE</Franqueado>
        </CarregaMunicipioFranqueados>
    </NewDataSet>
</string>";

$simples = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

//Pega o segundo...
$segundo = $simples->NewDataSet->CarregaMunicipioFranqueados[1];
//Pega o codigo
$codigo = $segundo->{'Codigo_Municipio'};
$municipio = $segundo->Municipio;

echo "Esse é o codigo: $codigo";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Esse é o municipio: $municipio";
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar...
Na verdade esse codigo xml esta em uma URL, eu teria que passar um parametro para pegar algumas informações, como a cidade pelo codigo.
Exp. <Codigo_Municipio>3100203</Codigo_Municipio> como parametro para imprimir a cidade <Municipio>ABAETE</Municipio>

Comment: Entendi ... nesse caso, quem fez o web-api? Cada web-api é uma coisa bem diferente, então precisaria saber mais sobre esse web api específico. Ou será que está *buscando* um web-api que possa fazer isso? Ou talvez está usando um mas não tem documentação?

Comment: Então, ele esta nesta url (http://vallesw.azurewebsites.net/api/municipiosfranqueados)
Mas é provisorio apenas para testes
Eu creie um site que irá buscar a cidade, endereço e tel
quando for alterado no sistema ira alterar no site automaticamente
porém eu não estou conseguindo tratar este xml por url

Comment: Se receber todo esse XML pelo Web API, a única maneira de extrair os dados é como mostrei na resposta. Se você quer receber um ou dois dados do WebAPI baseado em alguns parametros, vai ter que alterar o próprio WebAPI para te retornar dados específicos dependendo dos parametros.

Comment: Tem como usar o seu codigo usando uma URL? em vez de colocar o XML no proprio codigo?

Comment: Sim - em vez de colocar direto numa variável, pega usando o [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php).